# representation of boolean db column in asp grid view

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a column in my database which accept true or false value.  I want to display its value grid view column and using below code (my db column name is IsCancelled):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="کنسل شده" SortExpression="IsCancelled">
                                <ItemTemplate>%#Boolean.Parse(Eval("IsCancelled").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %></ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

but I'm getting following exception:

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   App_Web_jcvfb4rq.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

Comment: A missing tag opening exists before response write tag %#. Maybe it causes the error.

Comment: Seems you are getting NULL value too from DB..

Comment: i add missing tag, but not solved
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="کنسل شده" SortExpression="IsCancelled">
                                <ItemTemplate><%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("IsCancelled").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %></ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below solution if you are using **C#**. Please note that IIF is not available in VB.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="کنسل شده" SortExpression="IsCancelled">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%#IIf(Boolean.Parse(Eval("IsCancelled").ToString()), "Yes", "No")%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

In case you are using **VB** and looking for similar solution then use below code.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="کنسل شده" SortExpression="IsCancelled">
    <ItemTemplate><%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("IsCancelled").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

However same can be done at server side, using below code.

```
Protected Sub GridName_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridName.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        If e.Row.Cells(13).Text = "True" Then
            e.Row.Cells(13).Text = "Yes"
        Else
            e.Row.Cells(13).Text = "No"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: i do this by it has error:
Error: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'

Comment: @saeedgarmsiri Did you try adding `.ToString()`? like `Boolean.Parse(Eval("IsCancelled").ToString())`

Comment: @  Amnesh Goel yes of course i did that...
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="کنسل شده" SortExpression="IsCancelled"> <ItemTemplate><%# (Boolean.Parse(Eval("IsCancelled").ToString())) ? "Yes" : "No" %></ItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: @saeedgarmsiri I have updated my answer.. check that.. and use IIf

Comment: @ Amnesh Goel i did but there is error when use single qoute:
Error: Too many characters in character literal

Comment: @saeedgarmsiri Did you check the updated answer with IIF?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90719/discussion-between-amnesh-goel-and-saeed-garmsiri).

Answer (score 0):

Did you face this problem if you debug your code without deploying? I suspect you get this error after deploy because the exception occur in "App_Web_XXX" which is compiled file.

So first we need to know if your local has such issue. If yes, then it's easier to debug to know if this is the exact line that having the issue.

Once you confirmed the exact line that has the issue. You can try the following:

1) Check and ensure that "IsCancelled" column is exists in that particular table that you called and there is no typo, as the name must match.

2) Check your select statement in the data source. Make sure your select command able to return that column.

3) Might not be relevant but you can try Convert.ToInt32, and check if the value is 1 or 0 instead.

Since the error is not about casting or conversion problem, it's probably complaining that it cannot find or read "IsCancelled".

Hope this helps.

Comment: it can read "IsCancelled"  because when i write below code it should column data.(if field value is true it represents "True" in grid view cell)
<asp:BoundField DataField="IsCancelled" HeaderText="کنسل شده"/>